# GitHub Actions: run test on staging branch after comment on a pull request

Tags: cypress, github-actions, jobs, pull-request, staging

I have a github actions workflow that runs my cypress tests after a comment on a pull request. The problem is that it seems to run the cypress tests against the master branch. I want the tests to run against the staging branch. How can I get the tests to run against the staging branch after a comment on a pull request?
Here is what my yaml file currently looks like:

```
name: Cypress Staging Tests
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  identify-staging-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: deploy to staging comment on pr
    if: contains(github.event.comment.body, 'Successful Gordon Deploy')
    steps:
      - name: Github API Request
        id: gh_request
        uses: octokit/request-action@v2.0.2
        with:
          route: GET /repos/:repository/pulls/:issue_id
          repository: ${{ github.repository }}
          issue_id: ${{ github.event.issue.number }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: github secret
      - name: Get PR information
        id: pr_info
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=branch::${{ fromJson(steps.gh_request.outputs.data).head.ref }}"
          echo "::set-output name=repo_name::${{ fromJson(steps.gh_request.outputs.data).head.repo.full_name }}"
          echo "::set-output name=pr_title::${{ fromJson(steps.gh_request.outputs.data).title }}"
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
        with:
          token: dispatch token
          repository: ${{ steps.pr_info.outputs.repo_name }}
          ref: ${{ steps.pr_info.outputs.branch }}
  
  run-cypress-tests:
    needs: identify-staging-deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout 
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 12
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn ci:setup
      - name: Cypress Run 
        id: cypress-results
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4 
        with: 
          browser: chrome
          record: true
        env:
          CYPRESS_fileConfig: staging
      - name: Post PR Comment
        if: always()
        run: |
          gh api \
          --method POST \
          -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
          /repos/${{ github.repository_owner }}/repo_name/issues/${{ github.event.issue.number }}/comments \
          -f body='#### Cypress Tests: ${{ steps.cypress-results.outcome }}. See results at ${{ steps.cypress-results.outputs.dashboardUrl }}'
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: dispatch token
```

Comment: The job `run-cypress-tests` in your workflow is checking out the default branch i.e. `master`. You need to configure it with [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout)'s `ref` config parameter. See its [Usage](https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage) for more details. Apart from that, you are using its `@v2` which has deprecated NodeJS runtime so you should move to its `@v3`. In addition, `set-output` has been deprecated too in favor of [`GITHUB_OUTPUT`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter).

Comment: Maybe this link (https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25389) will help you as well

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. I had an extra layer of difficulty because the staging branch name changes every time we need to cut a new one. It always starts with staging, but the rest changes. Here is what I came up with:

```
run-cypress-tests:
needs: identify-staging-deploy
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0
  - name: Get staging branch name
    id: branch_name
    run: echo "staging_branch=$(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/staging*)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  - name: Checkout staging branch
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0
      ref: ${{ steps.branch_name.outputs.staging_branch }}
```